# devise FactoryGirl a user after its unconfirmation period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-confirmable

Using FactoryGirl and devise, how can I build/create a user after its unconfirmation period ?

I have first tried to set the `:created_at` to some week ago then I realized devise' `active_for_authentication` was actually based on `confirmation_sent_at`, however setting `confirmation_sent_at` to some weeks ago still didn't help as during the creation the `confirmation_sent_at` would be set to `Time.now`

I'd like to understand when/where this `confirmation_sent_at` is set (I was actually also afraid that calling `send_confirmation_instructions!` would resent a mail AND reset this confirmation_sent_at` but this wasn't the case...)

But more importantly, a valid FactoryGirl trait that would create an unconfirmed user after its unconfirmed access period.

Here is my (not working for unconfirmed) Factory so far

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    created_at        { Time.now }
    password          'qsdfghjklmù'
    confirmed_at      nil
    sequence(:email)  do |n|
      Faker::Internet.email(first_name.gsub(/[^\w]/, '_') + n.to_s)
    end

    transient do
      confirmed true
    end

    after(:build) do |user, evaluator|
      if evaluator.confirmed
        user.skip_confirmation!
        user.skip_reconfirmation!
      end
    end

    before(:create) do |user, evaluator|
      if evaluator.confirmed
        user.skip_confirmation!
        user.skip_reconfirmation!
      end
    end

    trait :unconfirmed do
      confirmed false
    end

    trait :after_unconfirmation_period do
      confirmation_sent_at do
        rand((User.allow_unconfirmed_access_for || 1.day).ago..10.days.ago)
      end
    end
```

end
end

Comment: Maybe you could try Timecop to freeze the time in the past for creation?

Answer (score -3):

Keep in mind that factory_girl is now factory_bot too. I know this doesn't answer your question, but will be helpful for you moving forward.

Comment: Since this is not an answer to my question it should have remained as a comment on the original post